# Display new select field if previous select field option is chosen

Tags: java, forms

[image of form showing misplaced dropdown field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omGun.png)

i have used SO to create some script that shows/hides a div containing a  field if the value of a previous field is "UpperGI". This works fine, but what i cannot do is use tr or td tags within the div.
I want the new field to be displayed in a simple table as the previous fields are.

```
function yesnoCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "UpperGI") {
  
        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    }
}

<form name="frm1" action="https://api-mapper.clicksend.com/http/v2/send.php" method="post">

  
  <table style="width:50%">
    
    <tr>
      <td>MRN:</td>
      <td><input name="customstring" id="mrn" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Specialty:</td>
      <td><select id="specialty" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
        <option value="Breast">Breast</option>
   
        <option value="UpperGI">UpperGI</option>
        <option value="Vascular">Vascular</option>
        <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>

    <div id="ifYes">
  
  
     Select Operation:
        <select id="Operation">
          <option value="LapChole">Lap Chole</option>
          
       
</div>
      </td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onClick="doall()"></td>
    </tr>
  
</table> 

 

</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` it's your row, `<td>` your case.

You can add some css to fix col size

```html
<script>

    function yesnoCheck(that) {
        if (that.value == "UpperGI") {
            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="frm1" action="https://api-mapper.clicksend.com/http/v2/send.php" method="post">


    <table style="width:50%">

        <tr>
            <td>MRN:</td>
            <td><input name="customstring" id="mrn" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Specialty:</td>
            <td><select id="specialty" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
                    <option value="Breast">Breast</option>

                    <option value="UpperGI">UpperGI</option>
                    <option value="Vascular">Vascular</option>
                    <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ifYes" style="display: none">
            <td>Select Operation:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="Operation">
                        <option value="LapChole">Lap Chole</option>
                    </select>
            </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onClick="doall()"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: excellent! thank you so much for taking the time to resolve this issue.